# Do I need to manually dispose a TraceListener?

Tags: c#, logging, garbage-collection, trace

Sorry if I miss it somewhere, but I cannot find any documentation if a [`TraceListener`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/debug-trace-profile/trace-listeners) is automatically disposed by the framework.

If I use this code:

```
        var traceListener = new DailyTraceListener("Logs", true);
        Trace.Listeners.Add(traceListener);
```

Do I need to manually call `traceListener.Dispose()`, assuming `Dispose` should be called for it to work properly? Note that the implementation will throw error if `Dispose` is called the 2nd time (I am trying to change it).

In [this article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34610819/how-do-you-dispose-a-tracelistener-properly):

> The listeners are disposed by the TraceSource

What/Where is the `TraceSource` in this case? Is it automatically disposed?

In short, is `Dispose` guaranteed to be called by .NET when the program exits?

Answer (score 1):

I did the test by myself. Seem like it is never called naturally. This is the demo code:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var listener = new TestTraceListener();
        Trace.Listeners.Add(listener);
        Trace.WriteLine("Test");
        listener.Dispose();
        Trace.WriteLine("After dispose");
    }
}

public class TestTraceListener : TraceListener
{
    public override void Write(string message)
    {
        File.AppendAllText("log.log", message);
    }

    public override void WriteLine(string message)
    {
        this.Write(message + Environment.NewLine);
    }

    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        this.WriteLine("Dispose called");
        base.Dispose(disposing);
    }

    ~TestTraceListener()
    {
        this.WriteLine("Destructor called");
    }

}
```

My text file is:

> Test
>
> Dispose called
>
> After dispose

After that, I try removing the `Dispose` call (`// listener.Dispose();`), this is the result:

> Test
>
> After dispose

Conclusion: `Dispose` is not called by default if the program exit naturally.