# FormClosing shutdown event doesn't write to file

Tags: c#, event-handling, shutdown

I have a backup power supply for my computer which is attached inline with it and the wall. When I pull the power cord from the wall, I have 2-5 minutes before the backup supply shuts down the computer. It is during this time that I want to write data to a file with the code below:

```
private void Form1_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.CloseReason.Equals(CloseReason.WindowsShutDown))
    {
        writeContents("Interrupted");
        sendMessage("PWR - The Spring Test Machine has stopped");                
        return;
    }

    if (e.CloseReason.Equals(CloseReason.UserClosing)) 
    {
        if (MessageBox.Show("You are closing this application.\n\nAre you sure you wish to exit ?", "Warning: Not Submitted", MessageBoxButtons.YesNoCancel, MessageBoxIcon.Stop) == DialogResult.Yes)
        {
            writeContents("Interrupted");
            return;
        }
        else
            e.Cancel = true; 
    } 
}
```

The problem is that it didn't work. I don't think the the closing event ever got called. Any ideas would greatly be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Have you subscribed to this event? That you just didnt paste it inside your form?

Comment: Forgot to mention that.  Yes I am subscribed.

Answer (score 3):

From here http://www.daniweb.com/software-development/csharp/threads/253249/application-exit-does-not-trigger-the-formclosing

> when you use taskmanager to "kill" the appliction, it doesn't fire any
>   events, It simply stops the execution, This is how you close an
>   application that has frozen. if you waited for it to handle any
>   events, then it would still be frozen.
>
> as for when you restart the computer or shutdown, the event will be
>   called only if there is enough time, they system tells all
>   applications it is shutting down and only gives them a short amount of
>   time to handle business before it kills them. Windows 7 will show a
>   dialog telling you which applications are still busy and ask you if
>   you want to kill them and shutdown, or cancel. But as for XP, it just
>   kills them after X amount of seconds.

That's pretty much how I would have imagined the behavior of FormClosing... Would Application.ApplicationExit Event be a better event to listen for?

Comment: Thank you for the information and the suggestion.  I will try ApplicationExit and see if that will work.

Answer (score 1):

Here is some usful info about Properties of FormClosing event:

[Bug in FormClosingEventArgs.CloseReason?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3631490/bug-in-formclosingeventargs-closereason)

And you can try using switch statement, like here:
[Detect reason for form closing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1623756/c-sharp-detect-reason-for-form-closing)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it works cuase i need to check it first and im not infront of my machine now .. but have you also tried the other elements of the CloseReason enum ? 
try TaskManagerClosing  .
In any case try first to throw a message( messagebox ) to see if you actually have the correct CloseReason you want and also don't forget to use the e.Cancel = true if you dont want the pc to close everytime you check it . 
After that check if the method you have for writting to the file is ok .

maybe this will help also 
[Prompt user to save when closing app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/462903/prompt-user-to-save-when-closing-app)